# Unable to retreive user properties (collections like contacts)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to modify a user his outlook contacts, however im unable to even obtain them using the graph client.
The application is basically a service which authenticates using a client<>secret.
Am I missing out on permissions or am i approving it the wrong way?

I tried the following code:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(Startup.Configuration["AppConfiguration:Office365:ClientId"])
                .WithClientSecret(Startup.Configuration["AppConfiguration:Office365:ClientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(Startup.Configuration["AppConfiguration:Office365:TenantId"])
                .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider ccp = new ClientCredentialProvider(cca);
_confidentialClient = new GraphServiceClient(ccp);

User user = await _confidentialClient.Users["someone@something.com"]
    .Request()
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.Id,
        u.Contacts
    })
    .Expand(u => new
    {
        u.Contacts
    })
    .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list user contacts you have to call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/contacts
```

Graph client:

```
await _confidentialClient.Users["someone@something.com"].Contacts.Request().GetAsync();
```

If you want to modify contacts check documentation:

[Create contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

[Update contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)